# Calling Angular Directive's controller functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive for a chart:

```
.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        ...
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.toggleAnimation = function() {
                ...
            };
        },
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

And I'm using it like so:

```
<div ng-controller='foo'>
    <chart></chart>
</div>
```

Where `foo` is:

```
.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    // TODO: call chart's toggleAnimation
});
```

Now, how do I call the `toggleAnimation` function on the `chart` directive from within `foo` controller?

Or is this not how the setup should be? What I'm trying to do here is create a function for my `chart` directive that allows whatever's consuming it to turn a variable in the directive to true/false.

Comment: why don't you just pass a variable to chart which fires the function when the variable changes?

Comment: So the link function would watch that variable, yes?

Comment: well, you need to set up a watcher

Answer (score 1):

```
.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            toggle: "@" // pass as string - one way // you could also make this an attr if you want
        },
        ...
        controller: function($scope) {

        },
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            ...

            var toggleAnimation = function() {
                ...
            };

            // when you change this value, it will toggle the animation
            // logic which will check the values of this variable so you can do if statements and modify animations
            scope.$watch('toggle', function(newVal, oldVal){
                console.log(newVal);
                if(parseInt(newVal) === 1)
                    toggleAnimation();
                else if(parseInt(newVal) === 0)
                    ; // do something else like toggle back
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller='foo'>
    <chart toggle="myVariable"></chart>
</div>
```

Controller JS

```
.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    // TODO: call chart's toggleAnimation
    $scope.myVariable = 0;  // initialize to this value

    function clickSomething(){
        $scope.myVariable = 1;  // change, hence fire animation
    }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main mechanisms by which data can flow between specific directives or controllers. Data can either flow *down* the scope hierarchy (which usually mirrors the DOM tree) using scopes and expressions, or it can flow *up* the hierarchy using directive controller APIs. Both of these mechanisms entail one directive communicating with one other specific directive.

A third communication mechanism is scope events. This mechanism is about one directive communicating with *zero or more* other directives/controllers which it doesn't necessarily know about.

Which mechanism to use depends on the specific scenario. The following sections give an overview of each, followed by a round-up of the trade-offs of each. (In the specific example you gave I'd use the first, but you seem to be interested in the general mechanisms and not just in your specific example.)

---

The idiomatic way to pass data *down* the tree is to provide the chart access to data from its parent scope. In that case, it would be used like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Foo">
    <chart animated="chartAnimated"></chart>
</div>
```

The `chartAnimated` in the above is a scope variable inserted by the controller. Here's how that looks in the `Foo` controller:

```
.controller('Foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.chartAnimated = true;
    $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
        $scope.chartAnimated = ! $scope.chartAnimated;
    };
});
```

The chart directive then needs to support this new attribute, which can be achieved using the `scope` property in the directive declaration:

```
.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            // This requests that Angular parse the expression in the 'animated'
            // attribute and write a function for it into the scope as
            // 'animationEnabled'.
            'animationEnabled': '&animated'
        },
        link: function link(scope, iElement, attrs) {
            // Now we can watch the expression to detect when it changes.
            scope.$watch(
                scope.animationEnabled,
                function (isEnabled) {
                    // This function will be called once on instantiation and then
                    // again each time the value of the expression changes.
                    // Use ``isEnabled`` in here to either enable or disable animation.
                    console.log('Animation', isEnabled ? 'is enabled' : 'is disabled');
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

---

Although it's not really applicable to your given example, let's also explore the other data flow technique I mentioned, where data flows *up* the tree.

In this case, a parent directive can expose an API to a child directive. This is, for example, how the `ngModel` directive interacts with its parent `form` directive, or how `ngSwitchWhen`interacts with its parent `ngSwitch`.

The key here is the `require` property on the directive declaration, which allows a directive to depend on another directive either on the current element or on some parent element. For the sake of this example, we'll look for it on any parent element.

Let's make a contrived example of a parent directive with many children that it wants to keep track of for some reason:

```
<parent>
    <child name="foo"></child>
    <child name="bar"></child>
    <child name="baz"></child>
</parent>
```

We'll define the `parent` directive first:

```
.directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            this.children = {};
            this.registerChild(name, child) {
                console.log('Got registration for child', name);
                this.children[name] = child;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The `child` directive is where we can make use of the `require` mechanism:

```
.directive('child', function() {
    return {
        require: '^parent', // Must be nested inside a 'parent' directive
        link: function (scope, iElement, attrs, parentCtrl) {
            // Notice the extra 'parentCtrl' parameter above.

            // Provide an API for parent to interact with child.
            var child = {};
            child.doSomething = function () {
                console.log('Child', attrs.name, 'requested to do something');
            };

            parentCtrl.registerChild(attrs.name, child);
        }
    }
});
```

In this case we establish a bidirectional communication channel between the parent and the child, with the child initiating the channel using `require`, and passing to the parent an object through which it can communicate with the child. When `require` is used there is an extra argument to `link` giving the controller of the directive that was requested.

---

Finally, let's talk about events. These are best applied in a situation where you have a single directive (or indeed, any other code that owns a scope) that wishes to broadcast a particular notification to whoever is listening. For example, `$route` communicates with `ng-view` (and anyone else who is listening) using the `$routeChangeSuccess` event, and `ng-view` alerts the rest of the application that the view is ready via `$viewContentLoaded`.

Event watchers belong to scopes, and events propagate up and down the scope hierarchy.

If you're holding a scope, you can watch for any events that might pass by using `scope.$on`:

```
scope.$on(
    '$viewContentLoaded',
    function () {
        console.log('view content loaded!');
    }
);
```

If you want to *send* an event, you can either send a message *up* the scope hierarchy using `$emit`:

```
scope.$emit(
    'somethingHappened'
);
```

...or you can send a message *down* the scope hierarchy using `$broadcast`:

```
scope.$broadcast(
    'somethingHappened'
);
```

In some circumstances you wish to pass an event to the entire application, in which case you can `$broadcast` on the `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast(
    'somethingHappened'
);
```

One important thing to keep in mind with events is that they are a "point-to-multipoint" mechanism, which is to say that many different recipients may "see" the same message. This makes events a rather poor mechanism for directed communication between two specific participants, and so events should be used sparingly.

---

So there's an overview of three data-flow mechanisms for directives in AngularJS. There are different trade-offs for each:

- Passing data to child directives via scope keeps the child directive decoupled from the parent, but requires the parent directive (or, in your case, controller) to provide the data that the child needs.
- The `require` mechanism is best used to provide template constructs that require the participation of multiple strongly-related elements, such as in the case of `ngSwitch` where `ngSwitchWhen` exists only to be used with `ngSwitch`, and is of no use without it.
- Events are best used for broad notifications, where the sender doesn't especially care who receives the message, and the recipient doesn't necessarily know who sent it. In this case, sender *and* recipient are truly decoupled from one another, and there may not even *be* a recipient.

Comment: This is just a great and very detailed explanation. Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use `$scope.$broadcast` to broadcast an event to the child scope in the directive.  The directive would listen for that and then run the method when it hears the correct event:

```
$scope.$broadcast("toggleAnimation", this.textToBroadcast);
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/smaye81/q2hbnL5b/3/